# Java EE WebApp ServiceLoader loading external jar as plugin

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, plugins

I have a very simple POC setup where I deploy a JEE7 webapp on a wildfly 9.
Via a jaxRs Resource endpoint I can trigger a "plugin loader".

The PluginLoader does use a directory and scans for jar files in the directory, which URLs then will be fed into a URLClassLoader.

Afterwards I use the ServiceLoader to load implmementations of a simple interface from those URLs.

When the ServiceLoader starts iterating over the found implementations, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.test.MyIface: Provider com.test.MyImpl not a subtype
```

The structure is also very simple:
MyIface.jar is the interface.
MyImpl.jar is a implementation of MyIface, while it contains a META-INF/services file with the correct naming and content for MyIface..
The webapp itself only knows MyIFace of course.

In JavaSE using a simple main entry point and invoking the loader from there, everything works.
In JavaEE the services file seems to be ignored though..at least that is what I get from the exception.

I put it in src/main/resources/META-INF/services
and in src/main/resource/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services (as I read that already in context with SPI and webapps)

Comment: MyImpl must be loaded by a shared parent classloader.  "instanceof" does not work across classloaders

Comment: How exactly are you loading the "plugin" class/jar file? I guess you should (1) instantiate a `URLClassLoader` using the specified jar *AND* having as parent the web application's context class loader (2) use `ServiceLoader.load(Class, ClassLoader)` with the classloader you created.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos ah, I forgot the parent classloader OF COURSE, stupid me...That actually did solve my problems. If you want you can make this a actual reply and I will vote it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, the following 2 steps must be followed:

1. Instantiate a `ClassLoader` (the stock `URLClassLoader` will do) that knows both the targeted jar *AND* the classloader of the web application.

   - It needs to know the targeted jar obviously to load the service implementation
   - It needs to have the classloader of the web app as parent so that all the classloaders share the interface class; otherwise, even if the custom classloader loads the interface, you will run to `ClassCastException`s like *"MyIface is not an instance of MyIface"*
2. Specify the classloader you created using the `ServiceLoader.load(Class, ClassLoader)` method